# How to get all the points from point cloud residing on the surface of a given sphere

Tags: 3d, point-cloud-library

I have a point cloud consisting of [PointXYZRGB](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/structpcl_1_1_point_x_y_z_r_g_b.html). I have defined a sphere `s` in 3D space, hence following things are known-

1. Center `o` of the sphere `s` as `(x, y, z)`
2. Radius `r` of the sphere `s`

I want to get all points of this point cloud, which resides on the surface of given sphere.

```
std::vector<PointXYZRGB> getAllSurfacePoints(
                         pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud){
}
```

Comment: what do you mean on the surface? Within a certain distance from the surface? Since the points are floats it is unlikely any points are exactly at that radius

Comment: Brad: yes, you are right. A tolerance `t` can be assumed such that all the points on the surface having distance in range  from  `r + t` to `r - t` are valid.

Comment: Theoretically you would query 2 point clouds from the source cloud, one for each boundary; one within r+t and one within r-t. Then, 'subtract' the smallest cloud from the largest; i.e. remove all points from cloud r-t from the cloud r+t. In practice though, you can use the filter framework of pcl; See pcl::PassThrough< pcl::PCLPointCloud2 > http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_pass_through_3_01pcl_1_1_p_c_l_point_cloud2_01_4.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling this function once to remove inner points and again to remove outer points.

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr 
passThroughFilterSphere(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloud, 
pcl::PointXYZI sphereCenterPoint, const double radius, bool remove_outside)
    {
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr  filteredCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
        float distanceFromSphereCenterPoint;
        bool pointIsWithinSphere;
        bool addPointToFilteredCloud;
        for (int point_i = 0; point_i < cloud->size(); ++point_i)
        {
            distanceFromSphereCenterPoint = pcl::euclideanDistance(cloud->at(point_i), sphereCenterPoint);
            pointIsWithinSphere = distanceFromSphereCenterPoint <= radius;
            addPointToFilteredCloud = (!pointIsWithinSphere && remove_outside) || (pointIsWithinSphere && !remove_outside);
            if (addPointToFilteredCloud){
                filteredCloud->push_back(cloud->at(point_i));
            }
        }
        return filteredCloud;
    }
```